# MakeCert - is it possible to change the key size?

Tags: certificate, size, key, makecert

When I generate a certificate using MakeCert.exe, I want to change the key size from 1024 to 2048.

Is this possible? Or do I need to setup a certificate authority (CA)?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108020/886319) to an other topic which allow you to ask for a 2048 bits certificate to a third-party CA using certreq.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/shared.htm) the following syntax is used:

```
makecert -pe -ss MY -$ individual -n "CN=your name here" -len 2048 -r
```

Sorry I cannot test it, since I don't have Makecert.

Comment: I was able to use makecert from VS2010 to specify `-len 2048` param

Comment: The claim in another answer is that "-len 2048" only works if your CRYPTO\RSA keys folder does not already have a 1024bit key cached from a previous copy of the certificate; manual deletion of the key is required. This matches my observations.

Answer (score 1):

[A description of Makecert options can be found at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.80).aspx), but I didn't see an explicit one for setting the key length.

Comment: Cheers ISW, I have looked on MSDN but I couldn't see any options for setting the key size.

Comment: "makecert -!" will also give you help for all the advanced options including "-len".