# 'Makecert' for 2048 bits

Tags: .net, security

For my application I need to generate a certificate with 2048 bits. Is it possible to generate using the 'makecert.exe' tool?

If not, which tool can be used to generate the certificate?

Comment: You buy certificates.  It costs more than 1024 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Makecert with 2048 bits options. It works fine. I don't the earlier statement said on the MSDN site. But it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [SO Question about makecert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463657/makecert-is-it-possible-to-change-the-key-size)

**Update**

[OpenSSL](http://blogs.digitss.com/apache/openssl/generating-2048-bit-csr-with-openssl/) might be your answer.

Comment: I read "If you use the makecert.exe file to generate your signing key pair, be aware that it only generates a 1024-bit key" in the link below: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756995.aspx. Is it true?

Comment: You appear to be right.  According to the documentation, it can only make 1024 bit keys.

Comment: Anyone can help out to create a certificate for 2048 bits?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I created a configuration file (following [MS documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736326%28WS.10%29.aspx)) to do the work which you can use with the following command (assuming that the conf file called `config.inf`) :

```
certreq -New config.inf csr_file
```

Here is the content of the configuration file (which you'll have to adapt to your need) :

```
; /!\ DON'T MODIFY THIS SECTION
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"

; Here are the TUNABLE THINGS
[NewRequest]
; Edit the subject to match your needs
Subject = "C=FR,ST=Ile De France,L=Paris,O=MyGroup,OU=MyTeam,CN=MySite"
; Indicate if the private key is exportable or not
Exportable = TRUE
; Minimum key length : 2048 bits
KeyLength = 2048
; Key Usages
KeyUsage = 0xe0
; Indicates if the certificate is stored in the machine store or not
MachineKeySet = TRUE
; Format of the output CSR file, you should not have to change that
RequestType = PKCS10
; Specify the provider used to generate the private/public key pair, you can
; list all the available providers by typing the following command :
; `certutil -csplist`
ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
ProviderType = 24
```

Then, when you got back your certificate, you just have to import it with the following command :

```
certreq -Accept crt_file
```

Hope this will help :)