# How to purchase an X.509 CA certificate from a public root certificate authority

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, azure-iot-hub

I'm studying Azure IoT Hub and trying to connect my device to IoT Hub with x.509 certificate.
It worked with **self-signed cert**, but the official suggestion is to purchase a **root CA cert** from a trusted third party to sign device cert.

[Get an X.509 CA certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOp0f.png)

I did some research, but couldn't find where to purchase.

Can you give me a link? And how much will it cost?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at this similar ask : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477011/where-do-i-get-an-x509-certificate-from

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want a root CA cert, as those are not available to anyone but the certificate authorities themselves.

What you seem to be looking for, is a certificate *signed* by a root CA.

You can get one from [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), or from any of the commercial CAs like Verisign, Thawte, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning. If you purchase a certificate from a certificate authority that has been signed by a trusted root and you intend to use that to sign device s' X.509 certificates for authentication, make sure that you do not purchase an end entity certificate. That type of certificate is incapable of signing another certificate and will not work. Make sure the certificate you get is capable of signing other certificates.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has it's own CA. Because AWS thinks security is important and they are capable of a decent cloud product implementation.

Microsoft on the other hand is more worried about selling defender security E5 licenses, so security implementations are weak or require premium licenses. No account expiring, no Azure CA for devices.

This 3th party can fix your problem for IOT Hub.

https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/integrate-microsoft-iot-azure-iot-hub-and-provisioning-service

https://www.deviceauthority.com/solutions/keyscaler-identities/

https://www.keyfactor.com/platform/iot-identity-platform/